# Does the color of boxplot in Boruta in R depend on another package?

Tags: r, random-forest, feature-selection

I am trying to use plot the boxplot to show the variable importance but cannot get the boxplot to show the 4 different color, the plots which I get are black in color. I am using Boruta version 6.

Does the plot function depend on another package?

I have used the following code;

```
1. plot(boruta_output, las = 2, cex.axis = 0.7)
2. plot(boruta_output, colCode = c("green", "yellow", "red", "blue"), 
      sort = TRUE, whichShadow = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), col = NULL, 
      xlab = "Attributes", ylab = "Importance")
```

Comment: I think that it would be helpful for us to see the code that you used to generate the `boruta_output`

Comment: Not reproducible. The first example in `Boruta::Boruta` outputs an object that is plotted with 4 colors. Does your `boruta_output` have 4 attributes considered important?

Comment: @G5W  `boruta_output <- Boruta(x, y, doTrace=2)` x= data frame with predictors, y=factor for classification, y has 3 levels

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic Thanks, if I check the `attStats(boruta_output)` I can see that the predictors are divided into confirmed, rejected and tentative.